# Asara Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred ten?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20557

Answer (score 7, accepted):

210 are the years of *shi'bud Mitzrayim*. (*[Rash"i](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%92#.D7.A8.D7.A9.22.D7.99_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29)* on *B'reshis* 15:13)

Answer (score 7):

Iyov lived 210 years - seventy before his troubles, and 140 after them. (Bava Basra 15b, top, and Rashi there ד"ה אימא)

Answer (score 4):

Parshas Mikeitz (Braishis 42:2) Yaakov sends his sons to Mitzrayim saying, “**רְדוּ** שָׁמָּה” “go down to there.” Rashi points out that Yaakov specifically said "**רְדוּ**", “descend”, and not "לְכוּ", “go”, because  210 = רְדוּ to show that they will remain there for 210 years.

Answer (score 3):

210 is the total number of days in all the *Adar Rishon* months in a nineteen-year cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Qetoret recipe laid out in Masekhet Keritot ([6A](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=35&daf=6&format=text)), there are 210 *maneh* in the following combinations of samanim (spices):

- Tzori (70), Tzipporen (70), Helbenah (70)
- Tzori (70), Tzipporen (70), Levonah (70)
- Tzori (70), Helbenah (70), Levonah (70)
- Tzipporen (70), Helbenah (70), Levonah (70)

Answer (score 0):

The 210 years of exile are hinted in first seven sentences (Shemot 1:1-7) for there are precisely 210 letters. - Jewish Wisdom in the Numbers, '210'; Rokeach, op. cit. 1:7

3 mentions (Bereshit 46:27, Shemot 1:5, Devarim 10:22) of '70 migrants'. 3 x 70= 210 - Rokeach, Shemot 1:5

If you look at the ה , you can see a 'hidden' **י** and a **ר**. The sum of their gematria's equal 210. Slightly easier to make out through [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet#/media/File:Hebrew_letter_He_handwriting.svg) versus block or print Hebrew. (Mishnah Berura S36; Personal observations)

Comment: A ה is actually a ד and a י which is 14. (though Bedieved the Mishna Berura rules that if it was round like a ר it's still Kosher)

Comment: @DoubleAA - Thanks for this. Working on my Hebrew I glanced at the script ה and made the connection. Glad it has been noticed already. Gematriot I've used this formula on warrant unique results. Do you know the source for the Mishna Berura you cited? Would like to include when submitting this formula.

Comment: The Mishna Berura has a discussion of each letter's proper shape in a long appendix to Siman 36. See the beginning of the entry for ה.

Comment: I'm confused. Again, the MB says a Hey should be a Dalet and Yud, **not** a Reish and Yud. A Reish instead of a Dalet would bedieved not be invalid, but it's not the way it should be. Why then would the Gematria of the Reish version be significant?

Comment: @DoubleAA Before and up to your initial response, two things have been unclear to me: 1) How did I see that reish (unaware of MB S36); 2) If it's only bedieved, why is it working (i.e. mathematically and allegorically)? Your source was a huge. Though my hebrew puts me at a disadvantage, I Will work to clarify more.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Are you saying that because the reish is bedieved in matters of writing, using it elsewhere in a gematria or other abstract interpretation is issur-prohibited?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. There are no prohibitions regarding Gematria. It may be _meaningless_ to use a Reish, but that's not for me to decide. If you find meaning in it, go ahead.