# Is two hundred and ten a name of God?

Tags: number, mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names, gematria-numerology

Is there a name of God (derived through gematria, kabbalah or otherwise) associated with the number 210?

Comment: What have you got so far? Why are you asking specifcally about this number?

Comment: sheimot, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Along the lines of what @yehuda's asking, you could make this question easier for people to answer and more valuable for future readers if you [edit] in some information about where you've encountered this idea, such that you're motivated to ask the question. It could be as simple as "I think I once heard this in a class."

Comment: see this answer for exhaustive list of names of God http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/all-names-of-god

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6382/asara-umatayim-mi-yodeya